# Metrizability of a compact Hausdorff space whose diagonal is a zero set

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, compactness, separation-axioms

Let $X$ be a compact Hausdorff space and suppose the diagonal in $X\times X$ is the zero set of a nonnegative continuous real-valued function.  Why does this imply $X$ is metrizable?

Comment: What sort of machinery are you willing to accept? With some theory of uniform spaces, it's easy. Without, it looks much harder. Also, you need continuity of the function, otherwise it's wrong ($f(x,y) = 1 - \delta_{xy}$ with the Kronecker delta).

Answer (score 8):

$\newcommand{\cl}{\operatorname{cl}}$Suppose that the diagonal $\Delta$ in $X\times X$ is the zero set of a **continuous** non-negative function $f:X\times X\to\Bbb R$. (Continuity is essential.) For $n\in\Bbb N$ let $U_n=\{\langle x,y\rangle\in X\times X:f(\langle x,y\rangle)<2^{-n}\}$; clearly $U_n$ is open in $X\times X$. For each $x\in X$ and $n\in\Bbb N$ there is an open $B(x,n)\subseteq X$ such that

$$\langle x,x\rangle\in B(x,n)\times B(x,n)\subseteq U_n\;.$$

For each $n\in\Bbb N$ let $\mathscr{U}_n=\{B(x,n):x\in X\}$; $\mathscr{B}_n$ is an open cover of $X$, so there is a finite $F_n\subseteq X$ such that $\mathscr{B}_n=\{B(x,n):x\in F_n\}$ covers $X$. Let $\mathscr{B}=\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N}\mathscr{B}_n$; then $\mathscr{B}$ is a countable family of open sets in $X$. I claim that $\mathscr{B}$ is a base for the topology of $X$; if so, then $X$ is a second countable compact Hausdorff space and is therefore metrizable by the Uryson metrization theorem.

Suppose that $V$ is a non-empty open set in $X$, and let $x\in V$. Define $f_x:X\to\Bbb R:y\mapsto f(x,y)$, and for $n\in\Bbb N$ let $G(n,x)=\{y\in X:f_x(y)<2^{-n}\}$. Suppose that for each $n\in\Bbb N$ there is an $x_n\in G(x,n)\setminus V$, and let $\sigma=\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$; then $\langle f_x(x_n):n\in\Bbb N\rangle\to 0$. $X$ is compact, so $\sigma$ has a cluster point $y$. Since $f_x$ is continuous, it’s easily checked that $f_x(y)=0$ and hence that $y=x$. But this is impossible: $V$ is an open nbhd of $x$ that contains no term of $\sigma$. This contradiction shows that there must be some $n\in\Bbb N$ such that $G(x,n)\subseteq V$. It follows that $\{G(x,n):n\in\Bbb N\}$ is a local base at $x$.

Now fix $x\in X$, and let $V$ be any open nbhd of $x$. There is an $n\in\Bbb N$ such that $G(x,n)\subseteq V$, and there is a $y\in F_n$ such that $x\in B(y,n)$. Suppose that $z\in B(y,n)$; then $$\langle x,z\rangle\in B(y,n)\times B(y,n)\subseteq U_n\;,$$ so $f_x(z)=f(\langle x,z\rangle)<2^{-n}$, and $z\in G(x,n)\subseteq V$. Thus, $x\in B(y,n)\subseteq V$, where $B(y,n)\in\mathscr{B}$, so $\mathscr{B}$ is indeed a countable base for $X$, and $X$ is therefore metrizable.

Answer (score 2):

This should be well-known Šneider theorem asserting that a Hausdorff compact space with $G_\delta$-diagonal is metrizable (see, for instance, [Gru, 2.13](https://books.google.com/books?id=m8rNBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA433)).

[Gru] Gary Gruenhage. *Generalized metric spaces* in *[Handbook of set-theoretic topology](http://webfile.ru/6475714)*, ed. K. Kunen, J. Vaughan, North-Holland, 1984.