# Is there a sequence of nested entourages $\{U_n\}$ with $\bigcap U_n=\Delta_X$, if $X$ is compact Hausdorff uniform space

Tags: general-topology, uniform-spaces

Let $(X, \mathcal{U})$ be a compact Hausdorff  uniform space. It is known that $\bigcap \{U: U\in \mathcal{U}\}= \Delta_X$.

Is there a sequence $\{U_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ with $U_{n+1}\subseteq U_n$ and $\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb{N}}U_n=\Delta_X$?

Answer (score 2):

No, this only happens if $X$ is metrisable. This follows from [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/438003/4280), as then the diagonal is a closed $G_\delta$ in a normal space and hence a zero-set.

So take any compact Hausdorff non-metrisable $X$ for a counterexample e.g. Double Arrow ( $X \times \{0,1\}$ in the order topology induced by the lexicographic order) or $\omega_1+1$, or the one-point compactification of an uncountable discrete space, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Is there a sequence of entourages $\{U_n\}$ with $U_{n+1}\subseteq U_n$ and $U_{n+1}[x]\subseteq U_n[x]$?

Comment: I'm sorry to butt in, but doesn't $X$ being metrizable follow from $(X,\mathcal{U})$ being Hausdorff and compact?

Comment: @Keen-ameteur no, see the examples I gave, which are compact Hausdorff (and hence uniformisable)

Comment: @user479859 you can always build decreasing sequences of entourages, but they are useless. The $U_n[x]$, which are then also decreasing, are not a local base or something useful.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma, Thanks a lot. In my research $f:(X, \mathcal{U})\to (X, \mathcal{U})$ is a homeomorphism and $\dot{A}$ is an open set of $z\in X$.  Take a decreasing sequences of entourages $\{U_n\}$, $U_{n+1}\subseteq U_n$. Is there an entourage $U_k$ such that $f(U_k[z])\subseteq \dot{A}$?

Comment: @user479859 no, not necessarily.